Need to find an intersect of sequences inside fasta files (no standardized sequence names)
I have several multifasta files (each containing between 3,000 to 3,600 sequences). The sequence names were derived from the genome where the sequence was extracted and they bear no significance or cannot be matched with the other files. Even if they can, they do not represent the same sequence.
Toy example below.
.
├── set_01
│   ├── fasta_01.fa
├── set_02
│   ├── fasta_01.fa
└── set_03
    └── fasta_04.fa

Example contents of two multifasta files:
Fasta_1
>NMN003-protein1016_1
TTGAGCAAGTTGTACCCAGAGCATTTCAAGATAGTGCAATTTGATAATCAGAGTTCTGCGACCGTGACATCAAAGAATTGGAATAGAATCGCTGCAGTTGCTCCCAAGATAAAACTTTCCCTCACTGATACAGAACTTGAGGCATGCAAAGCTGGAGACGAACAGGCTCTTGTTTCTATATTGAAACGTGTTCACACCTTGCACACGGGGAAAGATCTGGCAGAGAGCAAGCAATCGACAAGACCAGTATCAACAAATGAGGATAGGTCGCTGACTAAGGGTCCTGTCTCTAAGCTTGGGGTGGCATTGAACGCCAACCATCAAAATCAGACCATCACTCAGGACCCTCTTAAATTTCTTGTAACGCGGAACCTCGATAACATACATCATACATCTGCTCATGAACAAACGACCTTTGCCACGGCAACGAACCTTTCAACCATCTTGGTCCATGGTGACGCAGATGGACTGAATGCTGCCAGCTCCAGACCAAACAACTCTATGCTGTCTATGCGACCATCCACGGCTGCCGTTGATAACGATGATATGGCCTTTAGGATGAATCCTGGTGCTACAGGTACATCCAATGA...
>ATCC388-protein1016_2
TTGAGCAAGTTGTACCCAGAGCATTTCAAGATAGTGCAATTTGATAATCAGAGTTCTGCGACCGTGACATCGAAGAATTGGAATAGAATAGCTGCAGTTGCTCCCAAGATAAAACTTTCCCTCACTGATACAGAACTTGAGGCATGCAAAGCTGGAGACGAACAGGCTCTTGTTTCTATATTGAAACGTGTTCACACCTTGCACACGGGAAAAGATCTGGCGGAGAGCAAGCAATCGACAAGACCAGTATCAACAAATGAGGATAGGTCGCTGACTAAGGGTCCTGCCTCTAAGCTTGGGGTGGCATTGAACGCCAACCATCAAAATCAGACCATCACTCAGGACCCTCTTAAATTTCTTGTAACGCGGAACCT...
>ATCC388-protein1873_1
GTGATGTCGGACGTGGGGTTTGTTATCCGGGAAAAGTGCCATTGGATGGTTCAGTGCTTTGTGGAAAAGCTTGTCGACGATGACACGCGGATGGATCTGAGCACGGACAGCCGCAACTATTACGTCCTCACCGAGTGTTATGCCTCTGACTCTCTTCAGGCCCTTGTTGTCACGAG...
.
.
.

Fasta_2
>ATCC388-protein3340_1
ATGACCTCCTGGGGAGGCTATCTTCTTGGGCTGTCGGACGGTAGCCTGCTTTTGGGCCAGCGTGAATCGAATGCTATTGAGTGGTCACTCATCGAAGTCTTCAGTGTGACGCTCCAAAAGATCCTTGTTGGTCCAACCCACATCTTTGTTGTGGGGATAGACGAAAGTGTTCAGTCTCGTACTCGTTTTGGCGGCGCTTTTTTGGCCCACCAATCATCAGGCCAGGCGCGTTCTGGGTT...
>NMN4432-protein3340_2
ATGACCTCCTGGGGAGGCTATCTTCTTGGGCTGTCGGACGGTAGCCTGCTTTTGGGCCAGCGTGAATCGAATGCTATTGAGTGGTCACTCATCGAAGTCTTCAGTGTGACGCTCCAAAAGATCCTTGTTGGTCCAACCCACATCTTTGTTGTGGGGATAGACGAAAGTGTTCAGTCTCGTACTCGTTTTGGCGGCGCTTTTTTGGCCCACCAATCATCAGGCCAGGCGCGTTCTGGGTTCTCCCTTGCTGTTTTTGCTTATTCTCAGAACAGAAGGCGTCACTCCTCAGGAACTGGCGCGACTTTAATCTTTC...
>ATCC3432-protein1677_1
ATGGAAACACCATGCTTTTCTATACCAACATCTACAACGGTAATCCAGCCCGAGCAGCCGATCGTTAGCACAGTCAATGAGTCTACTCCTTGTGCGGAGTACTCTATTCCAACCCAGATTTGGCTCGCTGACCAGCTTACAAAATTGAGCCCTGCACGTTTGGCTCCATTTGACGATTTACTGGAACCAATAGAGGTCCCTACAAAAACAAAAGTCCCGTTCTTGCAAGATGAGGAGCTAAAGGCTCGGGTTATCCAAGAGGCAGTACAAGCAGAGAAGGATCGGAGGGACTCAATGATGCTCAAGGCAAGAGGGCGGTTTGCACAGCTGGTGCATGAAAGCGCAACAGAAGGTAGGCCAAAGTCTGCAATCTTTCTGGCTCCGGAGCGAGCAGCCACTCAGTATTCAAAGTTAACCATTAATGAACCCGTCAATAATAGCGAGTCAAGAGAACCTACCGAACGATCCTGCTAGCGTTGATGCCCAGTATGAGACAAAAGATATAGATGCTAAAGCAATCAAGGCAAAATTAGATGAGAAATATGGGCAAAAACGCTTTAGGAATAATGTGTCAATGGAAAATAGCAGAATAGATATAATAAAAGAGAATACAAACGCTATACAAGGTACTCAGCCAATCGACCGTAGGCTGGTGGCACAGTTGAGACAAGAGCACGTCAGGAAACTTGGCGCAGGGAGAAATTCTTCAGAACTTAGGTAT...
.
.
.


I need to find the intersection among the fasta files in every set. What I mean is I need to define what sequences are shared among all the multifasta files, not by name but using sequence similarity.
By intersect I mean finding highly similar sequences (>95% identity)  present in all datasets (like a Venn diagram). Then, I would like to save these sequences in a new fasta.
Clarification:
I cannot match the sequences by name. Even if they are highly similar nucleotide sequences, the output of my previous tool produces a sequential number that is not traceable among the sets. (e.g. The sequences with the name >NMN001-protein_1 in fasta_01.fasta is not the same as the sequence with the name >NMN001-protein_1 in fasta_10.fasta or fasta_11.fasta)
Apparently, seqkit has a function (seqkit common) to check an intersect by sequence identity but both sequences must be an exact match. It does not allow any mismatch.
I am trying to adapt this answer from Biostars using BLAST but I wonder if someone knows a different tool for this or how to approach it.
#!/bin/bash
FILES=($(find . -type f -name "*.fa"))

for((i=0;i<${#FILES[@]}-1;i++))
do
    blastn \
        -query ${FILES[$i]} \
        -subject ${FILES[$i+1]} \
        -outfmt '6 qseqid qlen length slen qseq' \
    | awk '
        BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}
        {if($2==$3 && $2==$4){print ">"$1"\n"$5}}' > tmp.fasta
    cp tmp.fasta ${FILES[$i+1]}
done


How's your Python, this is relatively easy via BioPython.

What is an intersection ??

What do you mean by intersection? Are you interested in the fasta records that have identical sequence composition, or is an identical header line sufficient? Can you please give examples of the structure of the fasta files (e.g. the first few lines of each file)?

How would you go about it in BioPython, I though you could only retrieve by sequence ID.

I may have misunderstood the question, but you are looking for identical sequences IDs in different files. Is that right? I agree seqkit will do this, but BioPython will do. To be honest I'd do it via data engineering, but its complicated to implement.

Hi, just updated the question for clarity. I am not looking for the same sequence ID, those are meaningless in this context. I need to match them based on sequence similarity. Is that doable in biopython?

You can use blastn from within biopython but what is wrong with the Biostars code above, why do you need another approach?
